# NSSM startup batch scripts without visible console

Tags: batch-file, startup, nssm

I am not able to make NSSM runs a batch script with the console visible at desktop.
I already tried to set it as a interactive process but still its not showing.
Any idea?

Below are my commands to create the service.

```
nssm install "MyNginxStartup" "C:\project\nginx-1.18.0\start_nginx_server.bat"
nssm set "MyNginxStartup" DisplayName "NGINX Startup Service"
nssm set "MyNginxStartup" Description "Starts NGINX Server on Windows startup."
nssm set "MyNginxStartup" AppExit 0 Exit
nssm set "MyNginxStartup" AppExit 1 Exit
nssm set "MyNginxStartup" AppExit 2 Exit
nssm set "MyNginxStartup" Start SERVICE_DELAYED_AUTO_START
nssm set "MyNginxStartup" Type SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS
```

Comment: How many services can you think of which show a window? There's a reason why a none service isn't supposed to be run as a service.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Windows services run in a protected enviroment, that cannot directly interact with your desktop; there were workarounds left for backwards compatibility, but Microsoft removed them completely in Windows 10 version 1803. You can find more information on this topic here: https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086228-what-is-session-0-isolation-what-do-i-need-to-know-about-it-

If you just need to see what the server is doing, the best solution is to modify your batch file to log the server output to a file, if you need interactivity you will have to use some sort of client to remotely manage the server (if you are really desperate you could use this: https://serverfault.com/questions/583517/start-program-on-computer-startup-when-nobody-is-logged-on-and-show-the-window-w).